# How to call a function of a react component in other js files inside the project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

I have a React component file named FilterBox.jsx, it has a function with the following code:

```
addTimeFilter() {
   var clickedItem2 = sessionStorage.getItem("clicked_value");
   const fltr = TIME_FILTER_MAP['__time_range'];
   const vals = '2019-03-25T00:00:00 : 2019-03-26T00:00:00';
   const selectedValues = Object.assign({}, {"__time_range" : "2019-03-25T00:00:00 : 2019-03-26T00:00:00","BrandName" : clickedItem2});
   selectedValues[fltr] = vals;
   this.setState({ selectedValues, hasChanged: true });
   if (this.props.instantFiltering) {
      this.props.onChange(fltr, vals, false, true);
   }
}
```

I have another file which is a `.js` file. I want to call `addTimeFilter()` inside the `.js` file. Please help me how to do this.

I have tried to import it like this:

```
 import FilterBox from '../../FilterBox';
```

Then I tried doing this inside a function in the .js file to call the following function:

```
function select(){
     const filter = new FilterBox();
     filter.addTimeFilter();
}
```

But only the import FilterBox from '../../FilterBox' giving me errors

Comment: where you have defined your `addTimeFilter` function ? inside class or outside class ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to export the addTimeFilter. Then when you import the function try this:

---

```
import { addTimeFilter } from '../../FilterBox';
```

---

I'm kinda new to react too, but something like this should work! :)

EDIT: try to export the class with "export default FilterBox" in the line in your file

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `export` keyword before the function name to let other js files know what to import.

```
export function addTimeFilter() {
/.../
}
```

Comment: No it will not work,As I have already exported the whole component class with `export default FIlteBox ` My component name

Comment: Then import it  like `import addTimeFilter from '../../FilterBox';`  It should work

Comment: What is `FIlteBox` in `export default FIlteBox` because to export function or class (not for file) we keyword `export` .

Comment: FilterBox is my component/class name

Comment: Then use `import FIlteBox from '../../FilterBox';` instead of `import addTimeFilter from '../../FilterBox';`

Comment: I made this function global by window.prototype. It is working now.